# Laravel Team-Game relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm building a website that involves a schedule of basketball games. I have 2 tables for this: `teams` and `games`.

As for the relationships between the models. For Game I got this:

```
public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team\Team', 'home_team');
}

public function awayTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team\Team', 'away_team');
}
```

But what should I do for the Team model? By the `games()` method inside it, I want to get all the team's games, home **and** away, and for this I need to reference both `home_team` and `away_team` columns on the `games` table.

**EDIT**

My table structure

```
teams
-------
id (int, primary)
name (varchar[255])

games
-------
id (int, primary)
home_team (int - references `id` on `teams`)
away_team (int - references `id` on `teams`)
date (datetime)
home_score (int)
away_score(int)
```

Comment: please post your table structure

Comment: Are you defining two different foreign key 'home_team' & 'away_team' in the Games model from the same table/model 'team'?

Comment: I know this is an old question, just wondering how did you solve this to get all games (home+away)?

Answer (score 0):

try this. I hope this works

Team Model

```
public function hometeamgames(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Team\Game','home_team');
}
public function awayteamgames(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Team\Game','away_team');
}
```

To find all games of home team

```
    $hteam=\App\Team\Team::find($hteamid);
    $hgames=$hteam->hometeamgames()->get();
```